# VIsual Studio WinForm connecting to SQL Server Database: C# syntax to transfer the data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, winforms

So I am just learning .NET, WinForms, SQL Server and C#.... I previously have used VB and MS Access, so I know this is a lot different but I am looking for a place to start.

I typically used unbound forms for data entry in MS Access, then saved the data to tables on btn_Click, or button event handler with Visual Basic (DAO or SQL).

So I have experimented with Visual Studio, creating WinForms with VB.NET & C#, and SQL Server. I have learned how to created a WinForm, then through VS create a DB within, and databind form to database table.

I haven't been able to reproduce the unbound form, and saving to external database through code (btn click) though. So lets say I already have created a Database through SSMS, and am now creating a WinForm for data entry. Now on the btn click, I am looking for the C# code that would transfer that entered data from the form to a database table.

So for the sake of example let's say that the form only has one text box called txtData, and I want to transfer it to a Database named DBExample, in a Table named tblExample, and a field named fldExample.

Can anyone help me with this. I have looked up a lot online about doing this, but everything i came across has to do with databinding the control, and I am looking for doing it through code.

thanks
justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a good general reference on .NET data access, see

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx

or

http://www.startvbdotnet.com/ado/default.aspx

---

A more specific answer to your example problem:

The rudimentary C# syntax, filtering out potentially malicious data, to prevent SQL Injection is:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("SomeConnectionString")

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into tblExample (fldExample) Values (@fldExample)"; // Use a parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection
cmd.Connection = cn;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fldExample", txtData.Text);  // Set the value of the parameter to the value of the textbox.
// Use a try... catch...finally block to ensure the connection is closed properly
try
{
   cn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   lblStatus.Text = "Item Inserted";
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   lblStatus.Text = ex.ToString();
}
finally
{
   cn.Close(); // will happen whether the try is successful or errors out, ensuring your connection is closed properly.
}
```

PLEASE pay close attention to how to avoid SQL Injection.  This is very important, and it's something that newer developers often miss, because they, like you, are worrying about the basic syntax and getting the update to work.  You CAN build your SQL statement without parameterized queries, but it's best to learn it right immediately.

Here's an article on Parameterized queries.  http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/

And an article from OWASP on SQL Injection so you can see why I say it's important.  (Actually, you should become familiar with the OWASP site and ALL of the OWASP Top 10, but this article is relevant to your question.)  http://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

AND for a list of how to build connection strings, for SQL Server AND other DB's, my favorite reference is http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81

Comment: I forgot - You can also look into LINQ (expecially LINQ to SQL) as an option, rather than pure ADO.NET, but I think it's important to understand ADO.NET before digging into LINQ.

Comment: best answer I have ever gotten on this subject hands down! I really appreciate it, and all the resources as well. trying to teach myself this and its daunting. thanks man!

Comment: So just so I understand what you are saying about the SQL Injection right away, is pay attention to building with Parameterizard Queries versus not? is that what you are saying? thanks!

Comment: Yes. You should ALWAYS use EITHER Parameterized queries OR use stored procedures.  Never contencate strings like "Insert into tbl (someField) values ('" + Textbox1.Text + "')" - that's an open invitation to be compromised and destroy your data.  Of course, the OWASP article covers this.